# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement easy_install (from versions: )

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, easy-install, pycurl

> Python 2.7.12
>
> pip 8.1.2
>
> ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install `pycurl` using:

```
pip install pycurl
```

this is what I get,

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /tmp/pip-build-8EU20I/pycurl/

So, I tried updating setup tools like this:

```
pip install --upgrade easy_install -U setuptools
```

i got

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement easy_install
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for easy_install

I've no idea on what I'm missing. Please help me out!

Comment: `easy_install` is a command included with `setuptools`. Try upgrading it with just `python -m pip install -U setuptools`.

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Comment: `pip` and `easy_install` are probably not the issue here. Do you have `libcurl` installed, per the [installation docs](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#pycurl-installation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pycurl
```

this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are attempting to upgrade the `setuptools` that came installed in your system Python, which requires changes to areas of the file system a "normal" user won't have (it requires root privileges).

Prefixing the command with `sudo` might help, but you should ask yourself whether you really want to change the system Python, since some OSs require Python "as installed" for various system purposes.

It's a lot safer to install a second copy of Python somewhere you have write access to (I personally tend to use `/usr/local` but YMMV) and then you won't need to worry about breaking your system. Further, as long as you set your PATH to include `/usr/local/bin` you can just use the `python` command to run it.

Comment: i've edited the question. sudo is not an issue anymore.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the virtual environment folder and recreate/reinstall it using virtualenv sampleenv
.This may solve your problem